# Azure Function timeout after 5mins even though `functionTimeout` is set to `00:10:00` in `host.json`

Tags: python, azure-functions, timeout

I'm stumped here. I have an Azure Function with Python runtime, Consumption Plan, Timer Trigger.

Every time the Function runs it timesout at 5mins even though the `host.json` is set for 10mins.

`host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

Error:

```
Exception type  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException
Exception message   Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.daily_job
```

What am I missing here? Why is this occurring and how do I override it?

---

**EDIT 1: `functionTimeout` is definitely set in Azure.**

[image]

**Yet it always throws a timeout error:**

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**:

I had two `host.json` files, one in the project root (the correct one, but one I was not editing!), and one in the function directory (the incorrect one I was editing). I removed the incorrect one and edited the correct file and of course, the timeout is working as intended.

Comment: In consumption plan, default timeout is 5mins, you have increased it to 10min in your host json, it seems fine, but I doubt it is not properly deployed in your Az func app. Recheck, or redeploy once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AnandSowmithiran Said, recheck or redeploy the Azure Function App in order to make `host.json` values deployed perfectly in Azure Portal Function App.

You have written the **`functionTimeout`** attribute value correctly in **`host.json`** and working successfully in the local environment.

And you have to check the same Values of `host.json` are published or not in the Azure Portal Function App by going to Azure portal > Your Function App > App Files:

[image]

As mentioned in the Scale limits of Azure Functions [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits), 10 minutes is the maximum time out for consumption plan which looks fine and same should be present in Azure Portal Function App as shown in the above.

Comment: If I would have looked under `App files` like you were showing, I would have seen that I had a second `host.json` file there which was unedited. Thank you.